# Scraping of a website on a AJAX based Request C#

Tags: c#

I have a Website like this http://www.lfp.fr/ligue1/feuille_match/52255 and i want to switches between the tabs infoMatch and Statistiques but it shows me the Data of 1st page only and when i use the firebug to check the reponse it gives me this:
GET showStatsJoueursMatchmatchId=52255&domId=112&extId=24&live=0&domNomClub=AJ+Auxerre&extNomClub=FC+Nantes

```
string url="http://www.lfp.fr/ligue1/feuille_match/52255";
                    string getData = "?matchId=52255&domId=112&extId=24&live=0&domNomClub=AJ+Auxerre&extNomClub=FC+Nantes";
                    System.Uri uriObj = new System.Uri(url);
                    String Methode = "GET";
                    lgRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateDefault(uriObj);
                    lgRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateDefault(uriObj);    
    lgRequest.Method = Methode;
    lgRequest.ContentType = "text/html";
                    SetRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html");
                    SetRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                    SetRequestHeader("Content-Length", getData.Length.ToString());

    StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter
                (lgRequest.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
            stream.Write(body);
            stream.Close();
            lgResponse = (HttpWebResponse)lgRequest.GetResponse();
```

But it gives me the error "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type." And when i use the "POST" in Method, it gives the Response of HTML but only the First Page Data not Statistiques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try at the following address: http://www.lfp.fr/ligue1/feuille_match/showStatsJoueursMatch?matchId=52255&domId=112&extId=24&live=0&domNomClub=AJ+Auxerre&extNomClub=FC+Nantes

Just like that:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            string result = client.DownloadString("http://www.lfp.fr/ligue1/feuille_match/showStatsJoueursMatch?matchId=52255&domId=112&extId=24&live=0&domNomClub=AJ+Auxerre&extNomClub=FC+Nantes");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I have used a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) instead of `WebRequest` which makes the code much shorter and easier to understand.

Once you have downloaded the HTML from the remote site you might consider using an HTML parsing library such as [`HTML Agility Pack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to extract the useful information from the markup you have scraped.

Comment: O man!!! My Reputation is below 15 so i cannot tank your answer but I love You Darin :* Seriously i have wasted my 7 hours and you give me the solution in 10 minutes :* muaaaaaaaaaaaah